# Loader's onLoadFinished() on adjacent pages not called until view is recreated

Tags: android, android-viewpager, asynctaskloader

I am having difficulty implementing loaders properly. I read a lot of articles and stackoverflow posts, and tried various things. But nothing has solved this problem yet. I am using a viewpager with PagerSlidingTabStrip library to create a 3 tab layout (using FragmentPagerAdapter). And I am using 3 separate loaders to load data for these 3 tabs.

The problem is that when I first load my app, the adjacent tabs don't call loadInBackground() until I scroll over to those tabs even though FragmentPagerAdapter creates the adjacent fragments successfully. Strangely, once I rotate or press home and open the app again, the adjacent tabs start loading. This means that if the view gets destroyed and recreated, the loading begins.

I also tried using startLoading for the loaders in all 3 fragments (I believe my OnStartLoading method is properly configured. I am calling forceLoad() in that method). If I use startLoading, then loadInBackground() is called. And yet, onLoadFinished() isn't! And so my view still shows an empty spinning loader until I move to the adjacent tab.

So, in short, whether loadInBackground() is called or not, onLoadFinished() for adjacent pages is not called until the view gets recreated. (or of course if I simply move to those pages)

Anyone come across a similar problem? I feel like I have tried everything I can, and have no clue how to proceed with this issue.

Here's my onCreateView():

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.movie_grid, container, false);

    LoaderManager lm = getLoaderManager();
    lm.restartLoader(CONFIG_LOADER, null, new ConfigurationLoaderCallbacks());
    lm.restartLoader(MOVIE_DATA_LOADER, null, new MovieDataLoaderCallbacks());

    ...           

    return v;
}
```

My abstract AsyncTaskLoader class:

```
private D mData;

public DataLoader(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

@Override
protected void onStartLoading() {
    if (mData != null) {
        deliverResult(mData);
    } else {
        forceLoad();
    }
}

@Override
public void deliverResult(D data) {
    mData = data;
    if (isStarted())
        super.deliverResult(data);
}
```

My onResume():

```
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    // Call this to re-connect with an existing loader
    LoaderManager lm = getLoaderManager();
    if (lm.getLoader(MOVIE_DATA_LOADER) != null) {
        lm.initLoader(MOVIE_DATA_LOADER, null, new MovieDataLoaderCallbacks());
    }
    if (lm.getLoader(CONFIG_LOADER) != null) {
        lm.initLoader(CONFIG_LOADER, null, new ConfigurationLoaderCallbacks());
    }
}
```

Comment: Can I have a look at your FragmentPagerAdapter?

Comment: @wangqi060934 Sorry, I scrapped the project a while back. Thanks for the response though.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18700436/onloadfinished-not-called-on-offscreen-fragment-until-going-back. -> This solution works